# How to compute K-shell score of nodes in neighboring list in python?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

i have stored my graph in a dictionary instead of edge list. each key is a node and the list of values for that key show the neighbor ids of that node:

```
neighbors_dict = {
    1: [2, 3, 4],
    2: [1, 3],
    3: [1, 2, 4],
    4: [1, 3]
}
```

I want to compute improved version of k-shell decomposition which considers the iteration number that the node is processed and removed from list. But actually i dont know how to start and complete k-shell for this structure.I really appreciate the answer that solves my problem. i really need this. thank you.